# Why does my variable change in the certain function/statement only in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables

my variable won't update if I change it in a function. Here's the code:```

```py
my_var = None
def func(string):
    if string == "Hello":
        my_var = string
        print(my_var) # prints 'Hello'

print(my_var) # prints None
```

How can I update my variable for all the script?

Comment: You're not calling the method, with  `func()`, only the first and last lines of code are used (everything is executed, but method definition is useless if not called)

Comment: You need to read about variable scope. In any event -- it typically isn't a good practice to have a function mutate nonlocal variables as a side-effect. Have your function *return* something and then `my_var = myfunc(string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to actually call func, because for now, your code is same as

```
my_var = None
print(my_var)
```

So change to

```
my_var = None
func("Hello")
print(my_var)
```

Also, you need to tell your method to use the global `my_var` one, because if not it'll define a variable with the same name in the scope of the method, and the global one won't change

```
def func(string):
    global my_var
    if string == "Hello":
        my_var = string
        print(my_var)
```